# Foreach loop; Undefined index: position. Syntax appears correct though

Tags: php

I'm getting an `undefined index: position` error using the code below, yet I do not see any errors in anything that I am doing. Looks just like the example on the php page (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
$position_list = array(
1 => "Chair", 
2 => "SACA",
5 => "School",
0 => "Disabled",
);

foreach ($position_list as $priv_id=>$position) {
    $data['position'] .= '<option value="'.$position_list[$priv_id].'"'; //throws error here
     if ($position_list[$priv_id] == $privilege_id) {
            $data['position'] .= " selected=\"selected\""; 
        }
     $data['position'] .= '>'.$position.'</option>';   //throws error here
}
```

I commented the code where the errors are thrown.

Edit: $data['position'] is a whole different thing, it is not suppose to refer to the position used in the foreach array.

Edit2: Some more code. Here is what is at the end of this php file:

```
$page->html .= File::text_replacement( "add_user.inc", $data );
```

In a add_user.inc file I have a line like this:

```
<td><select name="privilege_id">%%position%%</select></td>
```

`%%position%%` will be replaced by the $data['position'] variable upon the File class being called. This is not meant to be $position.

Comment: @Vivek that would be a lot of code.

Comment: You'll get a notice if you try and append to a variable before initializing it.

Comment: @Vivek I added some more code, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @billyonecan actually this may be the issue! I will try to change this and see if this is the fix.

Comment: It **is** the issue :p

Comment: @billyonecan Yes, you are correct. I just changed this and it works now without the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>$data['position']`probably isn't defined. You *probably* mean`$data[$position]</s>.

Define `$data['position']` before your loop:

```
$data['position'] = '';
foreach ($position_list as $priv_id=>$position) {
```

Comment: Haha, poor choice of using position in the $data array as well, but yes this is correct. I have other uses of $data in other places before this foreach loop that have no issues. For example: `$data['lastname'] = $lastname;  `

Comment: Thanks, billyonecan beat you to it in the comments, but I will accept this when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

`$data` need to be an array and since you are appending string value to `$data['position']`, it need the index 'position' to first be defined, try:

```
$position_list = array(
1 => "Chair", 
2 => "SACA",
5 => "School",
0 => "Disabled",
);

if (!is_array($data)){//making sure $data is an array
    $data = array();
}
$data['position'] = '';//Creating the index 'position' before using it.
foreach ($position_list as $priv_id=>$position) {
    $data['position'] .= '<option value="'.$position_list[$priv_id].'"'; //throws error here
     if ($position_list[$priv_id] == $privilege_id) {
            $data['position'] .= " selected=\"selected\""; 
        }
     $data['position'] .= '>'.$position.'</option>';   //throws error here
}
```

Comment: $data is created as an array already. The issue was that $data['position'] was not initialized but was being appended to.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable $priv_id=>$position. It should be $data[$position] instead of $data['position']. You should change ur code to:-

```
foreach ($position_list as $priv_id=>$position) {
    $data['$position'] .= '<option value="'.$position_list[$priv_id].'"'; //throws error here
     if ($position_list[$priv_id] == $privilege_id) {
            $data['$position'] .= " selected=\"selected\""; 
        }
     $data['$position'] .= '>'.$position.'</option>';   //throws error here
}
```

Comment: But, I actually am trying to refer to this element in the data array. I just happen to have the same variable name as I used in the foreach array.